# how to open another activity using holder in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

hello am trying to open or launch detail activity using holder button to view detail description. how to do it in android studio

here is my code so far:

```
holder.cmdStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent specPage= new Intent(this, SpecActivity.class);
            startActiviti(specPage);
        }
    });
```

this code show red and can not function. how to code this right to open the activity in android studio

Comment: In place of "this", use context which you passed in Adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that:-

```
holder.cmdStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent specPage= new Intent(v.getContext(), SpecActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(specPage);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The Adapter isn't a subclass of Context so it will fail to call `startActivity`. I also don't really see why you would use the context from the Button... But to each their own

Comment: v.getContext().startActivity(specPage); it will work.

Answer (score 0):

packageContext required by the intent might not be right, in this case "this". Also, you should not open an activity directly from the holder, instead use an router-listener approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Context` passed inside `onCreateViewHolder()`. You can't use `"this"` as a Context inside `onBindViewHolder()`

```
    @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, viewGroup, false);
           /* this one declared inside RecyclerAdapter*/
            this.context = mView.getContext();

            MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(mView);
            return vh;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong object to Intent constructor, when you use 'this' inside onClickListener, you are passing onClickListener interface in place of context. You simply need to pass view context in place of 'this'.
Below code will work.

```
holder.cmdStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent specPage= new Intent(v.getContext(), SpecActivity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivitiy(specPage);
    }
});
```

Comment: `startActivity` isn't available in the subclass of an Adapter. this code won't compile.

Comment: @Zun You are right, we need context for startActivity() also. edited my code

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a `context` inside `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.cmdStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent specPage= new Intent(context, SpecActivity.class);
        context.startActiviti(specPage);
    }
});
```